# Cascade Update on non-primary key in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to implement cascade update and I have searched online for the Fk constraint. I found the solutions like
http://sqlandme.com/2011/08/08/sql-server-how-to-cascade-updates-and-deletes-to-related-tables/

and that blog explain the process pretty good. I am not sure that dose this only works on PK or we can set up the cascade update/delete on non-pk fields also.

I have two tables.

**tblregistration**:

- UserID (PK)
- UserName
- CompName

etc

**tblposting_detail**:

- Bidid (pk)
- UserID (Fk with tblregistration)
- CompName

Now when a user edit his/her profile and update the company name, that is updating the `compname` in `tblregistration`, what I want here is that `compname` update also in my `tblposting_detail` on the same user who have updated his/her profile.

I have read some article saying that cascade update and delete gives unexpected results sometimes so its not preferred all the time and better to have two different update SQL statement instead on cascade update.

Could any one help me understand the process and best practice for this particular problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing `CompName` in the `tblposting_detail` table?

Comment: `CASCADE` can only be applied to foreign keys - and seeing your `compname` column isn't a FK, you cannot do this. Also: why is the `compname` stored in two places and requires to be updated twice? This is a bad design - not normalized - the `compname` should be stored just once, so if you update it - it's done.

Comment: Awesome. I thought so i made some basic mistake and thought that  there could be a way to solve this problem with my design, I will update the the design and normalize the table so i can apply the cascade update. And just to clear i ahve to set FK constrain on tbl_posting table on UserID(FK) which maps to Userd(PK) of tblregistration table right?

Answer (score 2):

Cascade update and cascade delete give perfectly predictable results. They give unexpected results only when developers are ignorant of their *predictable* results.

The target of a foreign key constraint must be a set of columns that are unique--the set of columns must have either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint.

In your case, tblregistration.CompName isn't unique. (Probably *can't* be unique.) You *could* mimic cascades using triggers, or by revoking permissions on the tables and requiring application code to use a stored procedure, but you're better off dropping the column CompName from tblPosting_detail. Use a SELECT query with a join when you need the data that's in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it by introducing a "super-key" that covers both your existing PK and the additional columns that you want to have cascade:

```
create table tblregistration (
    UserID int not null primary key,
    UserName int not null,
    CompName int not null,
    constraint UQ_reg_target UNIQUE (UserID,CompName)
)
go
create table tblposting_detail (
    Bidid int not null primary key,
    UserID int not null references tblregistration (UserID),
    CompName int not null,
    constraint FK_post_reg FOREIGN KEY (UserID,CompName)
       references tblregistration (UserID,CompName) on update cascade
)
go
insert into tblregistration values (1,1,1)
go
insert into tblposting_detail values (2,1,1)
go
update tblregistration set CompName = 4 where UserID = 1
go
select * from tblposting_detail
```

Result:

```
Bidid       UserID      CompName
----------- ----------- -----------
2           1           4
```

But I agree with the others that you just probably shouldn't have this column in your second table. I'd also advise against using a `tbl` prefix on all of your tables.

(Note that, at this point, it's up to you whether you keep the FK on just `UserID` as well as the FK on `UserID` and `CompName`, or just retain the latter one)

Comment: Thanks Damien. I will stick to the first solutions of deleting compname from the tblposting table. i would love to vote up but dont ahve enough reps.